# Sort entity by multiple children values in EF Core

Tags: ef-core-3.1

So how would one go about sorting entities based on the composite value of multiple children? Here is an example model:

```
public class Product
{
  public int ProductId { get; set; }
  public string Name { get; set; }
  public string ProductGroup { get; set; }
  public ICollection<Option> Options { get; set; }
}

public class Option
{
  public int OptionId { get; set; }
  public int ProductId { get; set; }
  public Product Product { get; set; }
  public string Name { get; set; }
  public int NamePosition { get; set; }
  public string Value { get; set; }
  public int ValuePosition { get; set; }
}
```

And example data that looks like this (assume that we can't control the order in which products or options are added, so the primary keys are not useful for ordering):

```
insert into Product (Name, ProductGroup)
select 'Long, Thin Red Drapes', 'Red Drapes' -- product id 1
union all
select 'Short, Thin Red Drapes', 'Red Drapes' -- product id 2
union all
select 'Long, Wide Red Drapes', 'Red Drapes' -- product id 3
union all
select 'Short, Wide Red Drapes', 'Red Drapes' -- product id 4
union all
select 'Long, Thin White Drapes', 'White Drapes' -- product id 5
union all
select 'Short, Thin White Drapes', 'White Drapes' -- product id 6
union all
select 'Long, Wide White Drapes', 'White Drapes' -- product id 7
union all
select 'Short, Wide White Drapes', 'White Drapes' -- product id 8
go

insert into Options (ProductId, Name, NamePosition, Value, ValuePosition)
select 1, 'Length', 1, '84 inches', 2
union all
select 1, 'Width', 2, '25 inches', 1
union all
select 2, 'Length', 1, '64 inches', 1
union all
select 2, 'Width', 2, '25 inches', 1
union all
select 3, 'Length', 1, '84 inches', 2
union all
select 3, 'Width', 2, '42 inches', 2
union all
select 4, 'Length', 1, '64 inches', 1
union all
select 4, 'Width', 2, '42 inches', 2
union all
select 5, 'Length', 1, '84 inches', 2
union all
select 5, 'Width', 2, '25 inches', 1
union all
select 6, 'Length', 1, '64 inches', 1
union all
select 6, 'Width', 2, '25 inches', 1
union all
select 7, 'Length', 1, '84 inches', 2
union all
select 7, 'Width', 2, '42 inches', 2
union all
select 8, 'Length', 1, '64 inches', 1
union all
select 8, 'Width', 2, '42 inches', 2
go
```

We would want to sort the products by their length values, then by their width values, so the sorted ProductId list for 'Red Drapes' would be: { 2, 4, 1, 3 }.

It seems like there is an OrderBy, ThenBy solution here, using the sorted name positions as ordinals or something, but I can't seem to find it. So far the only solution I can wrap my head around is to build a special sorting trick in the controller that would make a composite value based on all of the children, along the lines of:

```
ProductId 1 = Long, Thin Red Drapes = Length:2, Width:1 = Composite "21"
ProductId 2 = Short, Thin Red Drapes = Length:1, Width:1 = Composite "11"
ProductId 3 = Long, Wide Red Drapes = Length:2, Width:2 = Composite "22"
ProductId 4 = Short, Wide Red Drapes = Length:1, Width:2 = Composite "12"
```

Then sorting by this composite value, we get { "11", "12", "21", "22" }, or the desired { 2, 4, 1, 3 } sequence.

But this feels awfully awkward, and would break if a product came along with 10+ possible option values.

This query would do the trick, aside from duplicating the items by the number of options:

```
select i.Name, o.NamePosition, o.ValuePosition
from SaleableItem i
join SaleableOption o on o.SaleableItemId = i.SaleableItemId
where i.ProductGroup = 'Red Drapes'
order by o.NamePosition, o.ValuePosition
```

Thanks for any comments or suggestions!